# SQL Server Express login failed for user domain\name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I created a c# program with the connection string

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|APSDB.mdf;Database=APSDB; Initial Catalog= APSDB; Trusted_Connection=True; User Instance=true;
```

It works using the computer I created it with, but upon using Advanced Installer and deploying it to my laptop to test if it works on a different environment, it utterly fails. The program runs, but once I do anything that accesses the database, it gives me the error:

> login failed for user domain\name.

I have checked the SQL Server Error Log, there is no Error 18456, State 38 anymore. It just says:

> 2016-08-24 17:32:03.57 spid69s     Starting up database ‘APSDB’
>
> 2016-08-24 17:32:03.57 spid69s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] ‘APSDB’. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
>
> 2016-08-24 17:32:03.57 spid69s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] ‘APSDB’. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
>
> 2016-08-24 17:32:03.57 spid69s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] ‘APSDB’. XTP Engine version is 0.0.

Upon changing the account SQL Server Express is using to start to my Local System, and re-run everything, on the error log it says that:

> Login Succeeded for User domain\name

but alas, the problem persists with my program.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504(v=vs.110).aspx pay attention to the `DataSource =` part where they use double `".\\"`

Comment: also if it works on the computer that you created it on.. and when you deploy it.. are the 2 machines on the same domain..? llok at [C# Connection Strings here](http://www.connectionstrings.com) under the Sql Server

Comment: @MethodMan On my desktop, ".\" works. It runs flawlessly, but upon adding ".\\", I get an "Instance Failure". I won't be able to port it to my laptop for testing since it doesn't run properly

Comment: start reading here.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt650905.aspx

Comment: Do you have a SQL Express installed and started in your laptop? From your connection string .\SQLExpress, it means you need to have a NAMED sql instance on your LOCAL computer.

Comment: I checked it out and I followed the instructions about adding an SSMS login, but upon doing so, it just tells me that "the login already has an account under a different user name"

Comment: @jyao, Yes I have installed SQL Express on my laptop. I can connect to it using SSMS. I can see the database there too, its just that on my program, it gives me the error, Login Failed. I'm unsure why, since that same user can access it through ssms.

Comment: check this link:
[http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40980/login-failed-for-user-domain-username-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40980/login-failed-for-user-domain-username-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456) hope it will help

Comment: @RayanBouni Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried all the suggestions on the link you provided but it still won't work. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Matt Hi! Thanks for your time. I inspected the database and check its users. its listed there as 'dbo' with the loginname as my windows account. its membership and schema is dbo.Owner.

Comment: @Seiren, if you connect .\SQLExpress using SSMS, you can check the error log, and then see what error message SQL Server logs, you should see something like Error 18456, Severity 14, State [X], where X is a number, if you can tell us this X, I believe we can figure it out.

Comment: @Matt, since the connection is trusted_connection = true meaning Seiren is using windows authentication, I think it has nothing to do with the sql login id you mentioned.

Comment: yes precisely. I'm using windows authentication.

Comment: @jyao To be on the same page, do you mean the error that logs when I connect using SSMS? because connecting through ssms is fine. its just the c# program that I created cant login with the same credentials.

Comment: @Seiren, since you already have log in errors, each log in error will be recorded in the sql server error log, you just need to use SSMS to connect to your sql instance, and then check the sql error log, and look for Error 18456, and I just need the State [X], i.e. the X number. For example, I manage to simulate a login error on my lap top, and here is what I get Message
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.

Comment: @Seiren, if you do have this Error 18456, it means your connection attempt has reached your SQL Server but failed for some reason. If you do  NOT see this error, it means your connection does not even reach the sql server. (For example, you do not have the correct sql instance name in your connection string)

Comment: @jyao Sorry for the confusion. I checked the error log just now, and I do see error 18456 with state 38

Comment: state 38 means you do not have default database for the login. You can check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/.

To solve the issue, you can set a default database for your login account in your .\SQLExpress instance.

Comment: To set default db for a login, you can run the following in SSMS

USE [master]

GO

ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\NAME] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[APSDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

Comment: @jyao I havent been able to use the code you provided because something came up with the error log, upon trying to smooth out the deployment, the error is still appearing that i cannot login, but now, when i check the error logs, it simply says "Starting up DB" and then 3 lines of initalize database ID (6). There is no more error 18456

Comment: @jyao Hi. I've been trying to fix it and I haven't been able to, but I have added more information on my post.

Comment: @Seiren, can you try to use SSMS (with your DOMAIN\ACCOUNT) to connect to .\SQLExpress instance and then just run two sql statements: use APSDB; select * from sys.tables;   just to see whether there is any error popping out.

Comment: @jyao I tried it, and no errors, it returns to me all the tables currently on the database. I wonder whats causing the error.

Comment: @Seiren, you need to monitor the error log, if you run your application and get error "login failed for domain\account" at time [X], you need to check your sql error log, and see whether there is error 18456 around time [X], if you do NOT see error 18456, it just means your app connection has NOT reached SQL server instance. If you DO see error 18456, please check the STATE number, and using the link I posted above to find out the exact reason.

Comment: @jyao I see. well it just says Starting up DB, then thats it. No more error. so its probably the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in logs SQL Server the next error:
"Error 18456, severity: 14. Estate: 38
Login failed for user 'YourUser'. Reason: the database cannot be opened 'YourDataBase'... "

Show in the properties of user in the Tab "User Mapping" if the database have check and correct permissions.

If you don´t have check and push the check show the error "Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405" you cah to do the next:

USE myDB
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa', 'true'

And see you that option of Database AUTOCLOSE is FALSE.
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/02/20/sql-server-starting-up-database-why-multiple-times-in-errorlog/